# How to add title in a csv file for saved variables in bean shell script?

Tags: beanshell

Im using Jmeter to extract datas and save in a csv file in mail notification,Im getting the data but i need to add headers for the variables saved

I need to get the titles for the saved variables in the csv file(for.eg.
Info   RefNum (Title)
Sucess xxxxxxxx(variables)

Comment: can you share some code ?

Comment: update = vars.get("update");
refno = vars.get("ref no");
txnid = vars.get("txn id");
created = vars.get("created");
statusu = vars.get("statusu");
error= vars.get("error");

f1 = new FileOutputStream("/home/test/Desktop/updatebyref.csv",true); 

p1 = new PrintStream(f1);
 this.interpreter.setOut(p1); 
print(update+","+refno+","+txnid+","+created+","+statusu+","+error);
f1.close();

Comment: please update your question with the code...

Comment: Im using Jmeter to extract datas and save in a csv file in mail notification,Im getting the data but i need to add headers for the variables saved,
I need to get the titles for the saved variables in the csv file(for.eg. Info    RefNum(Title) Sucess   xxxxxxxx(variables)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add print headers comma separated before data

```
print("Info,RefNum (Title),Transaction Id,Created, Success,Error");
print(update+","+refno+","+txnid+","+created+","+statusu+","+error);
```

Comment: @user11906934 so add headers line inside a Once Only Controller

Comment: Hi, i'm getting the title header for the data but getting the header for each and every line before data one after the other
RefNum TxnID ResTime Time Result
3246845xxxxxx2 1648-322036 310 2019-08-12 9:15:22 null
RefNum TxnID ResTime Time Result
170151xxxxxx9 1648-322037 330 2019-08-12 9:15:22 null

Comment: @ user7294900  ok will check it

Comment: i meant this result format i'm getting in csv file not in view tree output